# How to organize cells in different columns with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that looks like this. You'll notice the columns contain different social media links.

[image: currently looks like]

I would like for the sheet to look like this - with columns containing similar social media links.

[image: should look like this]
Is there a way to automate this categorization? [Here's the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tvs2DqaRZU0rvQ10rqSemUfC-XDk0nyGUyW3-elTr18/edit?usp=sharing) if helpful, thanks.

Comment: The sheet is always going to have the link values on columns B and C? I understand it will add more rows on it. Also, have you considered using [Apps Script with an onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started) trigger that runs every time a value is inserted on the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace the cell values of `Link 1` and `Link 2` with the website name that you want in that column then you can use `FILTER` to get values that  match your criteria.

If your data looks like this:
[image]

Then you can use the following formula in `F3` provided you've labelled the headings appropriately (facebook, instagram etc)

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, $B$3:$C), " ")), SEARCH(F$2,  TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, $B$3:$C), " "))), SEARCH($E3, TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, $B$3:$C), " ")))))`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but here's an option with a formula in one cell - `E2`. You can put this on another sheet if preferred:

```
=arrayformula(
{A2:C2;
query(
{
vlookup({sequence(counta(A3:A),1,1,2),sequence(counta(A3:A),1,1,2),sequence(counta(A3:A),2)},{sequence(counta(A3:A)*2),query({row(A3:A),A3:A,B3:B;row(A3:A),A3:A,C3:C},"where Col2 is not null order by Col2,Col3",0)},{2,3,4,4},0)
},"select Col2,Col3,Col4 order by Col1",0)
})
```

If you have more Link columns than just two, I can provide different code.

[image]